# determine row id on SharePoint from javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007

Using Sharepoint DFWP, I have put a button on the form (ThumbsUp -- Like).  When a user clicks this button, it will add 1 to a Like's counter for the record.  I will be using jquery to update the row...

My question is how do I get the rowID when I click the button.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the handler:

```
var id = $(this).closest('tr')[0].id;
```

or

```
var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

or if by "id" you meant its index, do this:

```
var id = $(this).closest('tr')[0].rowIndex;
```

Comment: When I tried your approach, it came up with null results for the variable. However, by using the below (and putting the id next to the button), I was able to get it to work: var id1a = obj.parentElement.nextSibling.innerText;

Comment: @mercer: Yes, I didn't have any code to work from. Just be aware that your solution uses some properties that do not have full cross-browser support. jQuery takes care of browser compatibility, but to give a proper solution, you need to update your question with some code so I'm not having to guess.